# html <base> tag functionality misunderstood?

Tags: html

I have simple IIS Structure:

- DefaultWebSite

  - testapp

**DefaultWebsite** - landing page reachable by going to 192.168.1.5

**testapp** - web application reachable by going to 192.168.1.5/testapp

testapp's index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test App</title>
    <base href="/testapp/" >
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/">Test Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using *base* tag to set base of the app, so when clicking on Test Link I would expect just to reload the page as it is pointing to documents root.
But this is not the case. Clicking on the "Test Link" takes me to the index of DefaultWebSite.

Is this the way how this should work or am I not understanding the the *base* tag correctly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `base` tag only applies for all **relative** URLs. So, with the base tag like `<base href="/testapp/">` the following would apply.

```
<a href="/index.html">link</a>
```

would refer to the DefaultWebsite.

But

```
<a href="index.html">link</a>
```

Would refer to your testapp.

Answer (score 1):

base only comes into play on relative hrefs. So

```
<a href="/">Test</a>
```

is not affected by base at all.

BalusC has a very informative answer on its uses at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1889957/451600